# Intranet ASP.NET Application Impersonation and Database Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, active-directory

For my intranet application, is it possible to have the users AD credentials passed to and used for authentication with the MSSQL database?  I currently have a hard-coded user/password in the web.config's connection string.

I would rather manage user access and permissions via SQL server than build my own.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Here's the MSDN Article about it [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)